# python split strings (even odd)

Tags: python, string, join, split, string-length

I want to take an even string and change the front half and the string and the back half of the string.  I want to be able to do the same with an odd number but keep the middle letter of the string the same.  Ive coded for the even number but I get an integer output instep of the new string

```
def split_and_join (my_string):
    a = len('my_string')
    if (a % 2) == 0:
        first_half  = a[:len(a)//2]
        second_half = a[len(a)//2:]
        modified_string = join.s(second_half, first_half)
    else:
        print(a)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_string = input("Enter string:")
    print((split_and_join)(my_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
def split_and_join(my_string):
    a = len(my_string)
    if (a % 2) == 0:
        first_half  = my_string[:a//2]
        second_half = my_string[a//2:]
        modified_string = second_half + first_half
        return modified_string
    else:
        first_half  = my_string[:a//2]
        second_half = my_string[a//2+1:]
        modified_string = second_half + my_string[a//2] + first_half
        return modified_string
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_string = input("Enter string:")
    print((split_and_join)(my_string))

# If input; "sachin" then code's output: "hinsac"
# If input; "kohli" then code's output: "lihko"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
def split_and_join(my_string):
    e = (_len := len(my_string)) // 2
    return my_string[e:] + my_string[:e] if _len % 2 == 0 else my_string[e+1:] + my_string[e] + my_string[:e]

print(split_and_join('abcd'))
print(split_and_join('abcde'))
```

**Output:**

```
cdab
decab
```